# How can I use Devise Authentication to validate that a sign up email address is from certain domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to make sure the only people with email address of a certain domain can signup for a site that is using Devise.

For instance if people sign-up with the email joe@mysite.com, they should get a confirmation email but if the sign up with joe@yoursite.com, they should get a error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uncommenting this line in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
# Regex to use to validate the email address
# config.email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i
```

and changing it to use the domain I wanted to limit to:

```
config.email_regexp = /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@mysite\.com\z/i
```

did the trick.

Comment: Nice find! You might want to escape the . in mysite.com though.

Comment: Very useful. If you want to whitelist multiple domains you can use the or operator `|` and group them like so:  `/\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)(@firstdomain\.com\z)|(@seconddomain\.com\z)/i`