# How do I validate that an email has a particular address, using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, authentication, devise

I'd like to make it so that people can only sign up with @mysite.com email addresses. How do I do this, using Devise? I can't find the answer on the Devise wiki, or anywhere else. Also, I tried the method described here ( [How can I use Devise Authentication to validate that a sign up email address is from certain domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320386/how-can-i-use-devise-authentication-to-validate-that-a-sign-up-email-address-is) ), but it didn't work.

Here's my regexp:

```
config.email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@myuniversity.edu$/i
```

Comment: If you are in control of the email addresses handed out at "myuniversity.edu" your regex looks ok, but otherwise your email_regexp is going to exclude many valid email addresses. How about underscore `_`? In fact, nearly anything is allowed on the localpart of an email address (to the left of the '@')

Comment: Tried putting the following in my user model instead, and it worked!


      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :email_regexp => /.+@myuniversity.edu$/i

No need for the attempted change in the devise.rb file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Stephen P. Modified the regexp accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should validate it using something like this:

```
/\A[\w+\-.]+@myuniversity.edu/i
```

This will get you most of the way to following the RFC