# Ruby on Rails: Devise - Permit only a specific E-Mail-Address pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to allow only registrations from e-Mail-Addresses such as

"firstname.lastname@example.com" and "example.com" should always be the same, allowing only people to register if they have a mailaccount on "example.com".

Do you have an idea? Thank you!

Comment: You can add custom validation to your User model, just like you'd do with other models.

Comment: And devise seems to need some additional confirguration: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise

Comment: I saw this article too. Isn't there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Ehh, it's pretty simple...

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320386/how-can-i-use-devise-authentication-to-validate-that-a-sign-up-email-address-is

Comment: That's even simpler, didn't know that!